# What's the advantage of `std::optional` over `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`?

Tags: c++, option-type, c++17, stdoptional

The reasoning of `std::optional` is [made by saying](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) that it may or may not contain a value. Hence, it saves us the effort of constructing a, probably, big object, if we don't need it.

[For example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), a factory here, will not construt the object if some condition is not met:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

std::optional<std::string> create(bool b) 
{
    if(b)
        return "Godzilla"; //string is constructed
    else
        return {}; //no construction of the string required
}
```

But then how is this different from this:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> create(bool b) 
{
    if(b)
        return std::make_shared<std::string>("Godzilla"); //string is constructed
    else
        return nullptr; //no construction of the string required
}
```

What is it that we win by adding `std::optional` over just using `std::shared_ptr` in general?

Comment: For one thing, it's more verbose

Comment: What do you gain by using enums and booleans when you can just use ints, or structured loops when you can just goto?

Comment: @molbdnilo I feel `std::optional` is taking it too far. Back then when I had these huge debates with my PhD supervisor, he always said that C is better than C++ because you can learn C from a 300 pages book.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist, may I ask what field is your phd in?)

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist, making things "easier" in the way you mean it is now always a good think. Higher level languages may have ridiculous amounts of syntactic sugar, that doesn't mean they are better or worse, they are just different. Also the mere fact that `std::optional` exists doesn't mean you should use it whenever possible. Different tools for different tasks. In this exact case it has more of a semantic value. It's like using `size_t` instead of `unsigned int`, but on a higher level.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall My PhD field is particle and atomic physics. Actually a better reasoning of using `std::optional` over `std::shared_ptr` is an one of the answers and makes sense to me, which is that no dynamic allocation is necessary. Btw, I disagreed with my supervisor all the time, and I don't think C is "better", but I'm just saying how it looks like to outsiders (I'm currently a C and C++ dev). Also I think the comparison with typedefs is not fair. I think typedefs, like `size_t`, are very useful for forward compatibility and are not new constructs in the language like `std::optional`.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist `std::optional` is not a new language construct, it's just a standard library type, like `std::string` or `std::size_t`. (BTW, I would recommend [Null References: The Billion Dollar Mistake](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare), by the man who invented them, Tony Hoare.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Will do.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> What is it that we win by adding std::optional over just using std::shared_ptr in general?

Let's say you need to return a symbol from a function with flag "not a value". If you would use `std::shared_ptr` for that you would have huge overhead - `char` would be allocated in dynamic memory, plus `std::shared_ptr` would maintain control block. While [std::optional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) on another side:

> If an optional contains a value, the value is guaranteed to be
> allocated as part of the optional object footprint, i.e. no dynamic
> memory allocation ever takes place. Thus, an optional object models an
> object, not a pointer, even though the operator*() and operator->()
> are defined.

so no dynamic memory allocation is involved and difference comparing even to the raw pointer could be significant.

Comment: `std::optional::value_or` is arguably worth it on its own also

Answer (score 11):

An optional is a nullable value type.

A `shared_ptr` is a reference counted reference type that is nullable.

A `unique_ptr` is a move-only reference type that is nullable.

What they share in common is that they are nullable -- that they can be "absent".

They are different, in that two are reference types, and the other is a value type.

A value type has a few advantages.  First of all, it doesn't require allocation on the heap -- it can be stored along side other data.  This removes a possible source of exceptions (memory allocation failure), can be much faster (heaps are slower than stacks), and is more cache friendly (as heaps tend to be relatively randomly arranged).

Reference types have other advantages.  Moving a reference type does not require that the source data be moved.

For non-move only reference types, you can have more than one reference to the same data by different names.  Two different value types with different names *always* refer to different data.  This can be an advantage or disadvantage either way; but it does make *reasoning about* a value type much easier.

Reasoning about `shared_ptr` is extremely hard.  Unless a very strict set of controls is placed on how it is used, it becomes next to impossible to know what the lifetime of the data is.  Reasoning about `unique_ptr` is much easier, as you just have to track where it is moved around.  Reasoning about `optional`'s lifetime is trivial (well, as trivial as what you embedded it in).

The optional interface has been augmented with a few monadic like methods (like `.value_or`), but those methods often could easily be added to any nullable type.  Still, at present, they are there for `optional` and not for `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`.

Another large benefit for optional is that it is extremely clear you expect it to be nullable sometimes.  There is a bad habit in C++ to presume that pointers and smart pointers are not null, because they are used for reasons *other* than being nullable.

So code assumes some shared or unique ptr is never null.  And it works, usually.

In comparison, if you have an optional, the only reason you have it is because there is the possibility it is actually null.

In practice, I'm leery of taking a `unique_ptr<enum_flags> = nullptr` as an argument, where I want to say "these flags are optional", because forcing a heap allocation on the caller seems rude.  But an `optional<enum_flags>` doesn't force this on the caller.  The very cheapness of `optional` makes me willing to use it in many situations I'd find some other work around if the only nullable type I had was a smart pointer.

This removes much of the temptation for "flag values", like `int rows=-1;`.  `optional<int> rows;` has clearer meaning, and in debug will tell me when I'm using the rows without checking for the "empty" state.

Functions that can reasonably fail or not return anything of interest can avoid flag values or heap allocation, and return `optional<R>`.  As an example, suppose I have an abandonable thread pool (say, a thread pool that stops processing when the user shuts down the application).

I could return `std::future<R>` from the "queue task" function and use exceptions to indicate the thread pool was abandoned.  But that means that all use of the thread pool has to be audited for "come from" exception code flow.

Instead, I could return `std::future<optional<R>>`, and give the hint to the user that they have to deal with "what happens if the process never happened" in their logic.

"Come from" exceptions can still occur, but they are now exceptional, not part of standard shutdown procedures.

In some of these cases, `expected<T,E>` will be a better solution once it is in the standard.

Answer (score 4):

A pointer may or may not be NULL. Whether that means something to you is entirely up to you. In some scenarios, `nullptr` is a valid value that you deal with, and in others it can be used as a flag to indicate "no value, move along".

With `std::optional`, there is an explicit definition of "contains a value" and "doesn't contain a value". You could even use a pointer type with optional!

---

Here's a contrived example:

I have a class named `Person`, and I want to lazily-load their data from the disk. I need to indicate whether some data has been loaded or not. Let's use a pointer for that:

```
class Person
{
   mutable std::unique_ptr<std::string> name;
   size_t uuid;
public:
   Person(size_t _uuid) : uuid(_uuid){}
   std::string GetName() const
   {
      if (!name)
         name = PersonLoader::LoadName(uuid); // magic PersonLoader class knows how to read this person's name from disk
      if (!name)
         return "";
      return *name;
   }
};
```

Great, I can use the `nullptr` value to tell whether the name has been loaded from disk yet.

But what if a field is optional? That is, `PersonLoader::LoadName()` may return `nullptr` for this person. Do we **really** want to go out to disk **every time** someone requests this name?

Enter `std::optional`. Now we can track if we've already tried to load the name **and** if that name is empty. Without `std::optional`, a solution to this would be to create a boolean `isLoaded` for the name, and indeed every optional field. (What if we "just encapsulated the flag into a struct"? Well, then you'd have implemented `optional`, but done a worse job of it):

```
class Person
{
   mutable std::optional<std::unique_ptr<std::string>> name;
   size_t uuid;
public:
   Person(size_t _uuid) : uuid(_uuid){}
   std::string GetName() const
   {
      if (!name){ // need to load name from disk
         name = PersonLoader::LoadName(uuid);
      }
      // else name's already been loaded, retrieve cached value
      if (!name.value())
         return "";
      return *name.value();
   }
};
```

Now we don't need to go out to disk each time; `std::optional` allows us to check for that. I've written a [small example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/eacqXxoWWP4K2a9P) in the comments demonstrating this concept on a smaller scale

Comment: "Now we can track if we've already tried to load the name and if that name is empty" - I don't understand this. Are you suggesting that `unique_ptr` in your example be replaced with a pointer to an `optional<std::string>`, or an actual `optional<std::string *>`, or ... ? Using a plain `optional<std::string>` member object doesn't give you the tri-state possibilities you discuss.

Comment: @davmac: I'm speaking of an `optional<unique_ptr<std::string>>` . [Here is a code example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/eacqXxoWWP4K2a9P)

Answer (score 3):

Importantly, you get a known, catchable, exception instead of *undefined behaviour* if you try to access the `value()` from an optional when it's not there. Thus, if things go wrong with an `optional` you're likely to have a much better time debugging than if you were to use `shared_ptr` or the like. (Note that the `*` dereference operator on an `optional` still gives UB in this case; using `value()` is the safer alternative).

Also, there's the general convenience of methods such as `value_or`, which allow you to specify a "default" value quite easily. Compare:

```
(t == nullptr) ? "default" : *t
```

with

```
t.value_or("default")
```

The latter is both more readable and slightly shorter.

Finally, the storage for an item in an `optional` is within the object. This means that an `optional` requires more storage that a pointer if the object is not present; however, it also means that no dynamic allocation is required to put an object into an empty `optional`.

Answer (score 0):

> What is it that we win by adding std::optional over just using std::shared_ptr in general?

@Slava mentioned the advantage of performing no memory allocations, but that's a fringe benefit (OK, it may be a significant benefit in some cases, but my point is, it is not the main one).

**The main benefit is (IMHO) clearer semantics**:

Returning a pointer usually means (in modern C++) "allocates memory", or "handles memory", or "knows the address in memory of this and that".

Returning an optional value means "not having a result of this computation, is not an error": the name of the return type, tells you something about how the API was conceived (the intent of API, instead of implementation).

Ideally, if your API doesn't allocate memory, it shouldn't return a pointer.

Having optional type available in the standard, ensures you can write more expressive APIs.